# Python stop increment a list in certain condition

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am trying to implement a simple left rotation in a list.
Please review the following 
code:`

```
def left_rotation(n,d,arr):
    temp = arr
    for i in range(n):
        print(temp[i])  # here is the problem
        if (i-d < 0):
            arr[i+n-d] = temp[i]
        else:
            arr[i-d] = temp[i]
    return arr
print(left_rotation(5, 4,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

When I put the `if-else` structure it fails to access the variable `temp` but when I remove the `if-else`, it works.
How do you explain that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to access"? In any case, the problem is that `temp = arr` doesn't copy the content. It just copies the reference (so `temp` and `arr` is the same object).

Comment: Its your logic of the `if else` that is faulty.

Comment: you can replace that function with just this line `arr= (arr[len(arr) - n:len(arr)]  + arr[0:len(arr) - n])` and print it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp = arr` does not copy the list. It only creates a new reference which points to the same list. To copy you can use `temp = arr[:]`

```
def left_rotation(n,d,arr):
        temp = arr[:]
        for i in range(n):
            print(temp[i])  # here is the problem
            if (i-d < 0):
                arr[i+n-d] = temp[i]
            else:
                arr[i-d] = temp[i]
        return arr
    print(left_rotation(5, 4,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

This should work.
Sample Output1:

```
>>> print(left_rotation(5,2,[1,2,3,4,5]))
1
2
3
4
5
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Sample Output2:

```
>>> print(left_rotation(5,1,[1,2,3,4,5]))
1
2
3
4
5
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```